# Use keyboard to scroll in Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x modal popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using a bootstrap modal to display builds logs for a continuous integration-style tool, and they are often quite long. I can scroll with the mouse scroll wheel (and by using the scroll bar, of course), but the arrow keys and pg-up/pg-dn don't work. Is there a way to get those working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your modal got `id="myModal"` and your content wrapped in a div with `class="modal-body"` use:

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').keydown(function(e) 
    { 
        if(e.keyCode == 40){$('.modal-body').scrollTop($('.modal-body').scrollTop()+10);}
        if(e.keyCode == 38){$('.modal-body').scrollTop($('.modal-body').scrollTop()-10);}

    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one modal in the page and you use .modal scrollTop() will always return the position of the first modal.
For a more general solution when you have many modals you can do this:

```
$('.modal').keydown(function(e){
    var modalid = $('.modal.fade.in:visible').attr('id');  
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        $('#'+ modalid +' .modal-body').scrollTop($('#'+ modalid +' .modal-body').scrollTop() + 10);
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 38){
        $('#'+ modalid +' .modal-body').scrollTop($('#'+ modalid +' .modal-body').scrollTop() - 10);
    } 
});
```